# Order statistics is minimal sufficient statistics for unknow density function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I'm trying to prove the problem, but there is a problem on definition of term.

The theorem that I use to prove it is [image]
However, what exact meaning of "family of densities ~ all have common support"?
As far as I understand, common support mean the same range of X and family means just set of {f0, f1, ..., fk}. Is it right?

In addition, in order to prove minimal sufficient statistics(MSS) of order statistics, I have to show T(X) = (X(1), ..., X(k)) = (f1(X)/f0(X), ..., fk(X)/f0(X)), where X's density function is one of fi(X)s.

Can I think that f0(X) = 1, and fi(X)=X(i) for X, because X(i) for i=1, 2, ..., k have common support? Then can I prove that order statistics is minimal statistics?

I'm very confused ;-(
If we can discuss with these problem, I will be very excited.

Comment: I think that the issue on common support is that $f_0(\mathbf x)>0$ almost everywhere in its support, so you can divide by it, and then you could reconstruct $f_i(\mathbf x) = f_0(\mathbf x)\frac{f_i(\mathbf x)}{f_0(\mathbf x)}$ almost everywhere in the support of $f_i(\mathbf x)$ meaning that the division does not lose useful information

Comment: The components of $T$ are not what is usually meant by "order statistics."

Comment: BTW, the notation is so awful that it's difficult to determine what the statements are trying to assert.  For instance, "$f_0(\mathbf x)$" is not a "density:" it's the *value* of a density function at some argument $\mathbf x.$  In part (b) it is not clear what "$k$" refers to.  Is it supposed to be one less than the cardinality of $\mathcal F$ or not?  Is the "$T$" in that part supposed to be the "$T$" previously defined or is it supposed to be a generic minimal sufficient statistic? Perhaps the context or previous stylistic examples in your source might clear up these questions.